# What happened to the other demons?

Tags: ending, the-conjuring-universe, the-conjuring

In [The Conjuring](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1457767/) we only get to see what happens to Bathsheba, but what happened to the other demons in the film? Are they harmless and still roaming in the house?

Comment: @Tom Are you sure the `ending` tag is justified? Doesn't seem to be especially about the ending of the movie?

Comment: @ChristianRau The original text actually said "in the end." Added the tag and then rewrote the text. Just didn't put it back in, but, with the ending tag there it's kinda redundant. I haven't seen the movie, so, if the OP's original phrasing of the question was off, then the tag might be unjustified

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the film, Bathsheba was a wicked woman, who killed off her child to please the devil. Other *ghosts* or *apparitions* as seen in the film are actually direct or indirect victims of Bathsheba.

> While researching the house's history, Ed and Lorraine discover that the house once belonged to an accused witch, Bathsheba, who tried to sacrifice her children to the devil and killed herself in 1863 after cursing all who would take her land. The property was once 200+ acres but has since been divided up into smaller parcels.

Bathsheba had cursed people who took or lived on her land. So even after she was killed, she continued to possess mothers and made them kill their children. So the other *demons* which you refer to are actually *NOT* demons, but the ghosts of the mothers who have committed suicides after Bathsheba made them kill their children. Also, *Rory* is one such murdered child killed by a possessed mother.

> Lorraine enters the passage and falls through the floorboards into the cellar, where she sees the spirits of people whom Bathsheba has possessed. All are mothers whom Bathsheba used to kill their children.

Bathsheba is the only one who wants to hurt the family, and possess Carolyn to make her kill her daughter. All the other ghost spirits are not actively tormenting, merely living their horrors in the afterlife. It was only Bathsheba who needed to be exorcised, while the other ghost spirits could have been ridden off with other means. Bathsheba was the *danger* to the family.

Links: [The Conjuring - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Conjuring)